# Writing NULL is not an essential thing in CREATE TABLE?

Tags: sql

```
EMP_NO : VARCHAR2(10)NOT NULL
------------------------------

EMP_NM : VARCHAR2(30)NOT NULL
DEPT_CODE : VARCHAR2(4)NOT NULL
JOIN_DATE : DATE NOT NULL
REGIST_DATE : DATE NULL
```

when I create table by using above one, is it okay to just write "REGIST_DATE DATE" instead of "REGIST_DATE DATE NULL"

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(EMP_NO VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
EMP_NM VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
DEPT_CODE VARCHAR2(4) DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,
REGIST_DATE DATE);
ALTER TABLE EMP ADD CONSTRAINT EMP_PK PRIMARY KEY(EMP_NO);
CREATE INDEX IDX_EMP_01 ON EMP(JOIN_DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The default is that columns may contain nulls - ie if you don't code anything, no *constraint* will be defined that allows nulls - they are already allowed..

Adding `NOT NULL` adds a constraint that disallows nulls.

There is no such constraint like `NULL`: Just leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

Null is the default behaviour in most DBs, so if you dont write it system will automatically make the column as NULL.